# Altering characteristics of 3-party buttons (!) in Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, button, uibutton

I'm doing an iPad app in Xcode 4.3

So, I am triggering a function and inside that function, I want to be able to alter the characteristics of other buttons. For example, upon clicking my button (that I made in Interface Builder) linked to the function, I want to have a load of other buttons (also in IB) change text/color.

I've tried the developer book and a good amount of time on google, but I can't find the question asked or answered in the way i'm trying to phrase it (I decided this was the most clear one in the end)

I know I can easily edit the name of the button I've used to call the function

```
[MYBUTTON setTitle:(NSString *) TITLE forState:(UIControlState) STATE];
```

but I can't figure out how on earth to edit other buttons I've added in the interface builder. Is this possible, or do I need to deal with the buttons more programmatically?

so far in my function, I've called the IBAction and made a load of tags to relate to the buttons that I want to change - am I heading along the right road?

Hope this is clear about what I'm trying to achieve, and be gentle with me, my objective C isn't that good yet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mark button properties or instance variables with the IBOutlet marker and then hook the buttons in Interface Builder up to your object.

Also, it isn't a good idea to have all capital letter variable names.  In C convention, those are usually reserved for preprocessor macros.

Comment: didn't notice your answer until after I posted mine, apologies for repeating what you already mentioned, good catch with the C convention!

Comment: Thanks for this. I put the variables in caps to make it clear for these purposes, but probably confused things!

I think what I might be asking then (I'm probably missing something obvious), is how do I change the properties of an Outlet, which sounds pretty basic! I'll go read up on it, but my examples book isn't helping!

Comment: because I can see that I want to call something like 'myButton.titleLabel = ....' but titleLabel is presumably a read-only attribute?

Comment: Ok, embarrassing discovery and now completely...all sorted! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

create IBOutlet properties for each button in your view controller, link them in IB or Storyboard and finally change their properties in your method :)